# Google cloud: NVIDIA driver failed to install on image from ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20190429

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Installing NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu1804 on Google Cloud failed.
The DKMS make.log file shows:

```
The major and minor number of the compiler used to
compile the kernel:
    gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
does not match the compiler used here:
    cc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0
```

The problem here when we install package gcc, it always install 7.4.0. There is no easy way to install 7.3.0 without manually install bunch of dependency packages.

Google updated their Ubuntu1804 image on May 2, 2019. which break this.

Any idea?

Comment: How are installing the drivers? It doesn't need compilation...

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud recommends installing the CUDA toolkit for Ubuntu instances:

```
curl -O http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1704/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#install-gpu-driver